# How to export Filtered items to list from SPO without creating Views

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any way to export the filtered data to excel from the SharePoint Online(O365) list without creating any view?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

How about not exporting but connecting to the list in question in excel directly?

You can edit the query in Power Query and add the filter you need there.

Another option would be to import the data directly from a rest endpoint. That way you can apply the filter during the query already.